# When was the last time that three penalties were at Old Trafford in a single match?

Tags: football, trivia

Does anyone know when was the last time that three penalties were at Old Trafford in one game or has this ever happened before? I can't think of this ever happening under Ferguson seen as referees in general were terrified of him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2014/03/16/mark-clattenburg-gives-liverpool-two-penalties-at-old-trafford-in-landmark-moment-4608510/), the Liverpool/Manchester United game on March 16, 2014 is the first time a referee has awarded an away team two penalties, let alone three, at Old Trafford:

> Mark Clattenburg has become the first referee to award the opposition two penalties at Manchester United during today’s game with Liverpool....
>
> No opposition team had been awarded two penalties at Old Trafford under the Sir Alex Ferguson reign, strengthening the belief Ferguson’s power has not been carried on by his successor David Moyes.

[Steven Gerrard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Gerrard) of Liverpool converted the first two penalties, but missed the third. ([Source](http://metro.co.uk/2014/03/16/demoralised-manchester-united-embarrassed-by-title-chasing-liverpool-at-old-trafford-4608842/))